# Print tree level by level including Empty node

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, tree, breadth-first-search

Here is my code to print tree in a level by level way. It needs to print an empty node as well to keep tree structure like full binary tree for elegancy reasons.

I'm wondering if anything you think could improve, including the efficiency and not sure if any bugs (I did testing, not found bugs). I'm especially wondering if for part of code -- "print the remaining all empty leaf node part" could be optimized (I mean if any smarted way to optimize the `while` loop to cover all logic, and skip this code snippet especially handling the last level).

The tree I tested in this example looks like:

```
 1
/ \
2  3
/\ /\
4  5 6
```

Here is the related output:

```
[1]
[2, 3]
[4, '$', 5, 6]
['$', '$', '$', '$', '$', '$', '$', '$']
```

---

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def printTree(root):
    buf = []
    output = []
    if not root:
        print '$'
    else:
        buf.append(root)
        count = 1
        nextCount = 0
        while count > 0:
            node = buf.pop(0)
            if node:
                output.append(node.value)
                count -= 1
            else:
                output.append('$')
            if node and node.left:
                buf.append(node.left)
                nextCount += 1
            else:
                buf.append(None)
            if node and node.right:
                buf.append(node.right)
                nextCount += 1
            else:
                buf.append(None)
            if count == 0:
                print output
                output = []
                count = nextCount
                nextCount = 0
        # print the remaining all empty leaf node part
        for i in range(len(buf)):
            output.append('$')
        print output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Node()
    root.value = 1
    leftNode = Node()
    leftNode.value = 2
    root.left = leftNode
    rightNode = Node()
    rightNode.value = 3
    root.right = rightNode
    leftleftNode = Node()
    leftleftNode.value = 4
    leftNode.left = leftleftNode
    rightleftNode = Node()
    rightleftNode.value = 5
    rightNode.left = rightleftNode
    rightrightNode = Node()
    rightrightNode.value = 6
    rightNode.right = rightrightNode

    printTree(newRoot)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few small changes:
Python has a styleguide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which programmers are recommended to follow. One of its recommendations is to use `lower_case` names for both variables and functions. `camelCase` is also accepted, if applied consistently (which it is in your code).

Your `if` conditions in the while loop repeatedly check if `node` exists. Just put all of them in `if node:`. Additionally, the checks for `node.left` and `node.right` are basically identical, they can be combined by looping over `for n in [node.left, node.right]:`.

Whenever you do a `buffer.pop(0)` you probably want a `collections.deque`. While for lists, popping on the left is O(n) and O(1) on the right, both operations are O(1) for a `deque`.

Python has the nice feature of multiple assignments, allowing things like:

```
count, nextCount = nextCount, 0
```

You are always creating an instance of a node and directly afterwards you assign the value. It is better to add a parameter for the value to the class definition:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

---

With these changes I get this code:

from collections import deque

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def printTree(root):
    buf = deque()
    output = []
    if not root:
        print '$'
    else:
        buf.append(root)
        count, nextCount = 1, 0
        while count:
            node = buf.popleft()
            if node:
                output.append(node.value)
                count -= 1
                for n in (node.left, node.right):
                    if n:
                        buf.append(n)
                        nextCount += 1
                    else:
                        buf.append(None)
            else:
                output.append('$')
            if not count:
                print output
                output = []
                count, nextCount = nextCount, 0
        # print the remaining all empty leaf node part
        output.extend(['$']*len(buf))
        print output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Node(1)
    leftNode = Node(2)
    root.left = leftNode
    rightNode = Node(3)
    root.right = rightNode
    leftleftNode = Node(4)
    leftNode.left = leftleftNode
    rightleftNode = Node(5)
    rightNode.left = rightleftNode
    rightrightNode = Node(6)
    rightNode.right = rightrightNode

    printTree(newRoot)
```

---

This is still not very efficient code. If you give `Node` a magic method to decide if it is `True` or `False`, your code can be greatly simplified. This method is called `__nonzero__` in python 2.x and `__bool__` in python3.x.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value='$', left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return self.value != '$'

    def __str__(self):
        buf, out = [self], []
        while buf:
            out.append("{}".format([node.value for node in buf]))
            if any(node for node in buf):
                children = []
                for node in buf:
                    for subnode in (node.left, node.right):
                        children.append(subnode if subnode else Node())
                buf = children
            else:
                break
        return "\n".join(out)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Node(1, Node(2, Node(4)), Node(3, Node(5), Node(6)))
    print root
```

This gets rid of all the counting and so on. It does, however, not print the last line of all missing nodes (which seemed odd to me anyways). Normally I would use `None` for an empty Node, not `'$'`, but it also works this way.

I also added `left` and `right`, as parameters to the `Node`, allowing a nested definition, which might be less readable if it becomes too big, but might come handy, when quickly generating a tree like here.

If you also add the magic method `__str__` to `Node`, you can just do `print root` (or any other node and all its subnodes).

If you insist on having each level printed like a list (to ease copy&pasting it), replace the line

```
out.append(" ".join(str(node.value) for node in buf))
```

with

```
out.append("{}".format([node.value for node in buf]))
```

If you want to learn more about magic methods, have a look [here](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#numeric).

Comment: Thanks Graipher, vote up. 1. I see you also have code `output.extend(['$']*len(buf))` outside `while` loop, is there a way to put it inside the loop in your mind (I might be wrong but I think one loop code might be more elegant)? 2. Any logical bugs or issues in your mind of my original code?

Comment: Hi Graipher, if you could response to my above question, it will be great. :)

Comment: @LinMa See updated answer, at the end. I propose a slightly different implementation (the algorithm is similar).

Comment: Thanks Graipher for the update and vote up. I do not quite agree "While for lists, popping on the left is O(n)", but I could be wrong. Do you have any official document said remove head of a list in python 2.7 takes time of `O(n)`?

Comment: BTW, in my original code, are there any logical bugs? :)

Comment: BTW, your code does not print the last level of pure leaf node. You can refer the output I expected in original post. :)

Actually it is one of my question, how to print last level of pure leaf node inside one while loop to make it more elegant. This is how you handle `output.extend(['$']*len(buf))` in your first code example.

Comment: I still don't see the sense in printing this row, because it will by definition always contain only empty nodes. however, have a look at the edited code.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, mark your reply as answer and vote up, Graipher. :)

Comment: BTW, Graipher, re-studied your code today. I think in each iteration of loop, you call `any` I think `any` is an `O(n)` operation in performance perspective, not sure in this way your algorithm will become overall performance `O(n*n)`? Thanks.

Comment: @Linma `any` is O(n) at worst, i.e. if none of the conditions is true. Otherwise it is O(m), where m is the position of the first true condition, m <= n. So yes, it might be slightly slower for a tree like `Node(0, None, Node(1, None, Node(2, None, Node(3, None, ...))))`, i.e. where the left node is always empty.

Comment: Thanks Graipher for the patience to explain to me. Vote up and have a good evening!